# Rotating Redis TLS Certificates Without Downtime

Tags: ssl, redis, tls1.3, google-cloud-memorystore, downtime

I am using Redis with TLS enabled, configured through the `tls-cert-file`, `tls-key-file`, and `tls-ca-cert-file` settings. I understand that to rotate these certificates, I need to update the certificate and key files. However, during this process, the client's connection needs to be re-established using the new CA certificate, which could potentially result in downtime.

I am seeking advice on how to rotate Redis TLS certificates without causing any downtime. What are the best practices or strategies for ensuring a smooth certificate rotation process while maintaining continuous service availability?

Similar to memorystore of GCP, maybe there be a way to have multiple server certificates at the same time. If so, it's possible to first update the client's connection and after that, retired the old TLS configuration.

Answer (score 0):

From the redis-cli, redis servers (not sentinels) can use

```
CONFIG SET  xxx
CONFIG SET tls-cert-key yyy
```

Once the commands are executed, the server now works with newly provided certs.

---

Config docs:
https://redis.io/docs/management/config-file/

```
# Configure a X.509 certificate and private key to use for authenticating the
# server to connected clients, masters or cluster peers.  These files should be
# PEM formatted.
#
# tls-cert-file redis.crt
# tls-key-file redis.key
#
# If the key file is encrypted using a passphrase, it can be included here
# as well.
#
# tls-key-file-pass secret

# Normally Redis uses the same certificate for both server functions (accepting
# connections) and client functions (replicating from a master, establishing
# cluster bus connections, etc.).
#
# Sometimes certificates are issued with attributes that designate them as
# client-only or server-only certificates. In that case it may be desired to use
# different certificates for incoming (server) and outgoing (client)
# connections. To do that, use the following directives:
#
# tls-client-cert-file client.crt
# tls-client-key-file client.key
#
# If the key file is encrypted using a passphrase, it can be included here
# as well.
#
# tls-client-key-file-pass secret

# Configure a DH parameters file to enable Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange,
# required by older versions of OpenSSL (<3.0). Newer versions do not require
# this configuration and recommend against it.
#
# tls-dh-params-file redis.dh

# Configure a CA certificate(s) bundle or directory to authenticate TLS/SSL
# clients and peers.  Redis requires an explicit configuration of at least one
# of these, and will not implicitly use the system wide configuration.
#
# tls-ca-cert-file ca.crt
# tls-ca-cert-dir /etc/ssl/certs
```